# Can we make dropdownlist in asp.net automatically post back the first item in the list

Tags: c#, asp.net

Here's the simple code:

```
protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    string word = DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text;

    generateSynomyn(word);

}
```

This code is not executed when I select the first item on the index. In order to execute the code for the first item I have to select any other item first, then only the first item in the `dropdownlist`.

Also, can we automatically post back or at least make the `selectItem` the first item on the `dropdownlist`?

Comment: Sorry, might be misunderstanding this. Why can't you just add those two lines into your Page_Load event as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make the `DropDownList` fire for the first item you should enter a blank item, so a selection has to be made:

```
//put this where you bind your items the first time
DropDownList1.Items.Insert(0, ""); //adds a blank item first in the list
//or something like this
DropDownList1.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("[ select an item ]",""));
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this on your Pre Render Event of your DropDown:

```
 DropDownList1.Insert(0, new ListItem("-Select One-", "0"));
 DropDownList1.SelectedIndex = 0;
```

Regards